# Is it faster to compute logic every time, access a database, a file, or a hashmap?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have a piece of logic that will be executed every so often when I user presses a button.  However, I had this thought: "maybe it would be more efficient if I just stored this info in a table, and grabbed it when I needed it instead of computing it every time.

So Here we go: **Which process would consume the least amount of processing time/resources?**

Background info: Object array might be 10 items on average (although one of the member variables of that object is another array with max 4 items).  Also, every time this object changes it gets sent to the App Engine in C++, and button textures are changed on the front end.  This App Engine is constantly running high priority processes, and can't be slowed down by lots of work in the UI thread.

Also if any Database, File, HashMap etc. were to be made, it would contain roughly 100 rows of Integers.  (HashMap might be able to condense some of these into common key/value pairs)

## 1) (not a terrible solution, but I feel like it's redundant in context, and can be improved)

```
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.size(); i+= 3) {
            objectArray.get(i).y = FOO_VALUE;
        }
    } else if (x % 3 == 1) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            if (i + 7 <= x) {
                i += 3;
            } else if (i + 2 <= x) {
                i += 2;
            }
        } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
            if (i + 2 <= x) {
                i += 2;
            }
        }
    } else { // == 2
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            if (i + 3 <= x) {
                i += 3;
            }
        } else
            i += 2;
    }
```

(I haven't written these yet, so bear with my pseudo code)

## 2) Generic File (Probably O(n) access)

- Get File.
- Grab line x from file
- Set object array accordingly.

## 3) Local Static Database (I feel like this is pretty slow accessing data)

- Get Dao object for a local static database
- Initiate simple query
- store the result
- set Object array accordingly

## 4) HashMap (probably O(n) creation, but O(1) access.  Has to be instantiated every app startup)

- Set hashmap on app initialization
- get(x)
- set Object Array accordingly

Comment: Benchmark. There’s no universal answer and time complexity means nothing here when there are massive differences between access times etc.

Comment: there's also more to code than just performance. maintainability is a thing. do you think people want to maintain your first solution ? using variables `x` and `i` only makes sense to the person who wrote it

Comment: Well I'm not saying the 1st one is readable, It's pretty much "magic logic".  That's partly why I want to store the values somewhere else since the data I need isn't completely dynamic.  I could set a ceiling on the number input from the user

Comment: will probably be a race between 1 and 4. if your logic stays as simple as this its definitely faster than accessing a DB or a File, especially since a file needs parsing as well.

Comment: using method 4. with lazy loading. loading from memory is far faster than loading from db or file.

Comment: There is a lot of options how to build the code like yours. Just some thoughts... If you have enough memory, HashMap if the fastest way to put and get an item by key (both ops O(1)). You can initialize it in lazy fashion and/or in a background thread, btw. But. If you need persistence (read/write, deserialization/serialization) anyway, why wouldn't use an embedded SQL engine like sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your usage. Generally speaking, a user's local phone storage is expensive and you don't want to populate it with unnecessary data. On the other hand, if you think your button will be frequently pressed by the user, the HashMap may be a better choice. But, instantiating a HashMap every time can affect your memory usage depending on the size - You can do a lazy instantiation of the HashMap. Otherwise, unless you're doing some heavy scientific computation, computing logic every time may be your best choice.